# How to avoid "The number of GET/POST parameters exceeded" error?

Tags: html, django, forms

I have created a custom admin page on my Django website, Where only administrators will be allowed and will be able to change objects and their attributes. 
The amount of objects is a lot (9220 exactly) and on admin page there are equal amounts of input fields as objects in that model.

This is the code:

```
<form action="{% url 'Home:AdminPrices' %}" id="mainForm" method="post">
{% csrf_token %}
{% for item in prices %}
    <ul class="row" style="width: 100%;padding: 0;background-color: white;height: 100px;display: flex;justify-content: left;white-space: nowrap;margin-bottom: 0;margin-top: 0;">
        <div style="width: 33.333333333333336%;background-color: white;display:  block;color: black;font-size: 0.8em;white-space: nowrap;text-align: center;font-family: 'Lato';padding-top: 25px;">{{ item.hashname }}</div>
        <div style="width: 33.333333333333336%;background-color: white;display:  block;color: black;font-size: 1.2em;text-align: center;font-family: 'Lato';padding-top: 25px;">{{ item.sug }}</div>
        <div style="width: 33.333333333333336%;background-color: white;display:  block;color: black;font-size: 1.2em;text-align: center;font-family: 'Lato';"><input type="number" value="{{ item.actual }}" name="prices_{{ item.actual }}" style="width: 100%;height: 100%;padding-bottom: 25px;background-color: white;border: 0;color: black;font-size: 1.2em;text-align: center;font-family: 'Lato';"></input></div>
    </ul>
{% endfor %}
    <input type="submit" id="mainSubmit" style="display: none;" name="submitPrices"></input>
</form>
<div onclick="document.getElementById('mainForm').submit();" style="background-color: black;border-radius: 5px;position: fixed;display: block;height: 50px;width: 200px;bottom: 0;left:0;right:0;margin: 0 auto;color: white;font-size: 1.5em;text-align: center;padding-top: 12.5px;cursor: pointer;">Submit</div>
```

Once submit button is pressed, Website crashes and prompts out this error:

> 2017-06-25 10:05:53,158: The number of GET/POST parameters exceeded
>   settings.DATA_UPLOAD_MAX_NUMBER_FIELDS. 2017-06-25 10:05:53,860: Error
>   running WSGI application 2017-06-25 10:05:53,934: TooManyFieldsSent:
>   The number of GET/POST parameters exceeded
>   settings.DATA_UPLOAD_MAX_NUMBER_FIELDS. 2017-06-25 10:05:53,934:
>   File
>   "/home/MTonskins/Tonskins/Selement/senv/local/lib/python2.7/site-packages/django/core/handlers/wsgi.py",
>   line 170, in **call** 2017-06-25 10:05:53,935:     response =
>   self.get_response(request) 2017-06-25 10:05:53,935:  2017-06-25
>   10:05:53,935:   File
>   "/home/MTonskins/Tonskins/Selement/senv/local/lib/python2.7/site-packages/django/core/handlers/base.py",
>   line 124, in get_response 2017-06-25 10:05:53,935:     response =
>   self._middleware_chain(request) 2017-06-25 10:05:53,936:  2017-06-25
>   10:05:53,936:   File
>   "/home/MTonskins/Tonskins/Selement/senv/local/lib/python2.7/site-packages/django/core/handlers/exception.py",
>   line 41, in inner 2017-06-25 10:05:53,936:     response =
>   response_for_exception(request, exc) 2017-06-25 10:05:53,936: 
>   2017-06-25 10:05:53,936:   File
>   "/home/MTonskins/Tonskins/Selement/senv/local/lib/python2.7/site-packages/django/core/handlers/exception.py",
>   line 76, in response_for_exception 2017-06-25 10:05:53,937:
>   response = debug.technical_500_response(request, *sys.exc_info(),
>   status_code=400) 2017-06-25 10:05:53,937:  2017-06-25 10:05:53,937:
>   File
>   "/home/MTonskins/Tonskins/Selement/senv/local/lib/python2.7/site-packages/django/views/debug.py",
>   line 84, in technical_500_response 2017-06-25 10:05:53,937:     html =
>   reporter.get_traceback_html() 2017-06-25 10:05:53,937:  2017-06-25
>   10:05:53,937:   File
>   "/home/MTonskins/Tonskins/Selement/senv/local/lib/python2.7/site-packages/django/views/debug.py",
>   line 316, in get_traceback_html 2017-06-25 10:05:53,938:     c =
>   Context(self.get_traceback_data(), use_l10n=False) 2017-06-25
>   10:05:53,938:  2017-06-25 10:05:53,938:   File
>   "/home/MTonskins/Tonskins/Selement/senv/local/lib/python2.7/site-packages/django/views/debug.py",
>   line 293, in get_traceback_data 2017-06-25 10:05:53,938:
>   'filtered_POST': self.filter.get_post_parameters(self.request),
>   2017-06-25 10:05:53,938:  2017-06-25 10:05:53,938:   File
>   "/home/MTonskins/Tonskins/Selement/senv/local/lib/python2.7/site-packages/django/views/debug.py",
>   line 167, in get_post_parameters 2017-06-25 10:05:53,938:     return
>   request.POST 2017-06-25 10:05:53,938:  2017-06-25 10:05:53,939:   File
>   "/home/MTonskins/Tonskins/Selement/senv/local/lib/python2.7/site-packages/django/core/handlers/wsgi.py",
>   line 128, in _get_post 2017-06-25 10:05:53,939:
>   self._load_post_and_files() 2017-06-25 10:05:53,939:  2017-06-25
>   10:05:53,939:   File
>   "/home/MTonskins/Tonskins/Selement/senv/local/lib/python2.7/site-packages/django/http/request.py",
>   line 311, in _load_post_and_files 2017-06-25 10:05:53,939:
>   self._post, self._files = QueryDict(self.body,
>   encoding=self._encoding), MultiValueDict() 2017-06-25 10:05:53,939: 
>   2017-06-25 10:05:53,940:   File
>   "/home/MTonskins/Tonskins/Selement/senv/local/lib/python2.7/site-packages/django/http/request.py",
>   line 397, in **init** 2017-06-25 10:05:53,940:     for key, value in
>   limited_parse_qsl(query_string, **parse_qsl_kwargs): 2017-06-25
>   10:05:53,940:  2017-06-25 10:05:53,940:   File
>   "/home/MTonskins/Tonskins/Selement/senv/local/lib/python2.7/site-packages/django/utils/http.py",
>   line 350, in limited_parse_qsl 2017-06-25 10:05:53,940:     'The
>   number of GET/POST parameters exceeded

I'm not quite sure how can i avoid it, Could i change the settings and set different limit specifically for this view? Or could i submit all these fields as one list? If not, Then what could be the solution? Can i specify `DATA_UPLOAD_MAX_NUMBER_FIELDS` setting to certain view? Thanks in advance.

Comment: How many items are there in prices?? also could you post the full traceback?

Comment: @FazilZaid There are exactly 9220 objects in the model Prices. I will update answer right now with full traceback.

Comment: @FazilZaid Updated the code, I know `DATA_UPLOAD_MAX_NUMBER_FIELDS` option might solve the problem, But could i specify the option to specific view only?

Answer (score 11, accepted):

Django's documentation states that settings shouldn't be changed anywhere other than the settings:

https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/1.11/topics/settings/#altering-settings-at-runtime

The solution, as you mentioned, is it increase the size of `DATA_UPLOAD_MAX_NUMBER_FIELDS` in the settings. Good luck!

Comment: Hello, Thanks for the answer. Just another question, Wouldn't this increase the server overloading risk when a lot of POST/GET requests will be sent by attackers? Because most of my website's views are taking POST requests, And specifically this view can only be accessed by administrators.

Comment: Potentially, but there are other levels of protection like CSRF. I'd wouldn't worry as much about the number of individual fields as the content of them!

Answer (score 3):

in settings.py just increase "DATA_UPLOAD_MAX_NUMBER_FIELDS" value or disabled checking for this value , where the Default is 1000:

for example

```
# to increase value
DATA_UPLOAD_MAX_NUMBER_FIELDS = 102400

# to disabled check 
DATA_UPLOAD_MAX_NUMBER_FIELDS = None
```

check Django docs on the following url :
https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/3.2/ref/settings/#data-upload-max-number-fields

I hope this helpful.