# The number of GET/POST parameters exceeded settings.DATA_UPLOAD_MAX_NUMBER_FIELDS

Tags: python, django

I got an error: "The number of GET/POST parameters exceeded settings.DATA_UPLOAD_MAX_NUMBER_FIELDS".

Error says that TooManyFieldsSent at `/api/upload`.

I wrote in my `views.py`.

```
def upload(request):
    id, array = common(request)

    if request.FILES:
        file = request.FILES['req'].temporary_file_path()
    else:
        return HttpResponse('<h1>NG</h1>')

    return HttpResponse('<h1>OK</h1>')

def common(request):
    id = json_body.get("access", "0")
    if id == "":
        id = "0"

    s = []
    with open(ID_TXT, 'r') as f:
        for line in f:
            s += list(map(int, line.rstrip().split(',')[:-1]))

    array = [s[i:i + 2] for i in range(0, len(s), 2)]

    return id, array
```

I post access & req data by using POSTMAN like:
[image]

I think this error is limitation of being able to send file size, so I added the code to settings.py

```
DATA_UPLOAD_MAX_MEMORY_SIZE = 100000000
```

But the error didn't solved. I read this page: [How to avoid "The number of GET/POST parameters exceeded" error?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/44745355/how-to-avoid-the-number-of-get-post-parameters-exceeded-error) as a reference. How should I fix this?

Answer (score 123, accepted):

as django's doc says, the value of DATA_UPLOAD_MAX_NUMBER_FIELDS is default 1000, so once your form contains more fields than that number you will get the TooManyFields error.

check out here: https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/stable/ref/settings/

so the solution is simple I think, if DATA_UPLOAD_MAX_NUMBER_FIELDS exists if your settings.py, change it's value to a higher one, or, if it doesn't, add it to settings.py:

```
DATA_UPLOAD_MAX_NUMBER_FIELDS = 10240 # higher than the count of fields
```

Comment: thx,ur answer.Your codes works for me.However,I cannot understand what is the difference of DATA_UPLOAD_MAX_NUMBER_FIELDS & DATA_UPLOAD_MAX_MEMORY_SIZE .I read documentation,but cannot understand the difference.

Comment: The latter is for limitation of memory comsuming.

Comment: What is the max value one can set `DATA_UPLOAD_MAX_NUMBER_FIELDS` to?

Comment: @RedCricket in django you can set it to None to disable the fields count checking. besides, there is not limitation as I know, as long as your web server can serve that much bytes of a request. Like, nginx has a default value 1 MB for `client_max_body_size`.

Answer (score 20):

This happened when I tried posting a huge list values to Backend. In my case I had the liberty of sending the list as a string, and it worked. Django by default has this check to prevent Suspicious activity(`SuspiciousOperation`).

However below setting will also work.

```
# to disable the check
DATA_UPLOAD_MAX_NUMBER_FIELDS = None
```

`You can set this to None to disable the check. Applications that are expected to receive an unusually large number of form fields should tune this setting.` From Django official documentation. https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/3.1/ref/settings/#data-upload-max-number-fields