# django deploy changes in settings.py

Tags: django, django-forms, apache2, mod-wsgi

I have a small problem with Django settings.

In my page I have some really big input and I got the error:

```
The number of GET/POST parameters exceeded settings.DATA_UPLOAD_MAX_NUMBER_FIELDS.
```

took me about 3sec google to find a solution

```
DATA_UPLOAD_MAX_NUMBER_FIELDS = None # None so it ignores the error -> change to big number results in the same error
```

In my local develop it works like a charm. On the server I did the same and after that:

```
service apache2 restart
```

but i still get the error.

Any ideas?

Comment: Does this answer your question? [The number of GET/POST parameters exceeded settings.DATA\_UPLOAD\_MAX\_NUMBER\_FIELDS](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/47585583/the-number-of-get-post-parameters-exceeded-settings-data-upload-max-number-field)

Comment: Saw this but the changed won't apply on the server.

Comment: Did you restart the server after making the change?

Comment: Well I restarted Apache2

Answer (score 0):

I found a soultion.
For some reason I don't know apache2 didn't load the whole `settings.py`.
I just reuploaded the entire App and restartet apache2 after that.
Maybe there was a bad path or something.